# print jobs on kindle fire hd

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire, printing

I have a kindle fire hd and I printed some papers but they had errors on them which are now fixed but the print jobs are still on my kindle and I can't clear all to erase them.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings- go to applications manager- select all applications- then use the pull down bar and select all applications. Find print spool and select it. Then press clear all data. You should be good to go, and the error in the notification window will be gone.

Comment: Yrs, thank you. Helping my father in law, and he had this question. I couldn't figure it out, so no way he would have found it under print spooler. Why you can't dismiss the messages directly, I have no idea.  Thank you!  In law tech support for the win!